# Changing a connection string from a local SQL attach MDF to Web Host SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

Trying to convert classroom code to my hosting site.

I'm having a tough time reasoning this out, I am relatively new to .NET MVC 4 and working in a somewhat restrictive environment on a "WinHost" server and playing within their rules.

The hosing site rules are:

> they assign you a server address (which is no problem) like "*10.2400.thisServer.com*", then they prefix all database names with something like *"USER_5777" + (my 5 char name)*. They require security to be *"Integrated Security=False"*

I am doing online MVC learning and have no problem with the local tasks and operation of the classroom code. But, I want to adapt these tasks and example projects to a real-time environment on my web host site, "WinHost" is who I use.

All classroom code assumes Microsoft SQL Server and local IIS. Below is an example of the current "web.config" that works perfectly on my local dev machine.

```
    <add name="MvcAuction.Models.AuctionsDataContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\MvcAuction.Models.AuctionsDataContext.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

As you can see it is an attached mdf in the "App_Data" folder

Here is the modified version of my "web.config" on the host.

```
    <add name="MvcAuction.Models.AuctionsDataContext" connectionString="Data Source=tcp:g09.winhost.com;Initial Catalog=DB_12345_auction;User ID=DB_12345_auction_user;Password=MonkeysUncle;Integrated Security=False;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I have created a database on the host site according to their rules as I pointed out above. But it causes an error with the following message:

*{"Model compatibility cannot be checked because the database does not contain model metadata. Model compatibility can only be checked for databases created using Code First or Code First Migrations."}*

Please help

Comment: Are you using Code First or Database First with Entity Framework?  Sounds like you need to either run the migration or publish your database.

Comment: You are correct Daniel. My learning curve was more like cliff diving. I was trying to treat Entity Framework and standard SQL connections in the same manner. Bad results were guaranteed. dbContext was another issue I was dealing with. The moral to my story was I didn't know as much about context database programming as I thought. So if anyone is looking for a quick fix on a similar problem. Take a deep breath there are several ways as usual to accomplish the same connectivity BUT the technology SQL and Object Context syntax is subtly different. One thing I saw in EF6 that I really wish EF 5 ha

Comment: Thanks you are correct

Comment: RobertM - Orlando; Which did you do? Publish or use Migrations.  I'm currently trying to get around this learning curve.